# Why is cv2 not available although it should have been installed with `poetry add opencv-python`?

Tags: python, pip, python-poetry

### Abstract of Error

The following command fails on jupyter notebook.

```py
import cv2
cv2.__version__
```

The error message is as follows.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'.
```

### My Attempt

#### poetry failed

My project uses poetry for package management and I first ran `poetry add opencv-python`.

The installation was successful and the version number was displayed by running `poetry show opencv-python` on the IDE terminal. However, I still got the same error on jupyter notebook.

#### pip success

Next, run `pip install opencv-python` on the IDE terminal, and the error disappears and I can now run it.

### My Question

- Why does pip work and poetry does not?
- How can I use poetry alone to manage my project without using pip?

### My Environment

- IDE: VSCode 1.81.1
- using DevContainer

  - image: jupyter/datascience-notebook:python-3.11.4
  - feature: ghcr.io/devcontainers-contrib/features/poetry
- run jupyter notebook on VSCode. The kernel is `python 3.11.4`
- put the `poetry.toml` file in the root of the project and added `[virtualenvs] create = false` to it.
- Here is the result of `poetry env info`:

```
Virtualenv
Python:         3.11.4
Implementation: CPython
Path:           NA
Executable:     NA

System
Platform:   linux
OS:         posix
Python:     3.11.4
Path:       /usr/local/py-utils/venvs/poetry
Executable: /usr/local/py-utils/venvs/poetry/bin/python3.11
```

- the output of `poetry env list` is nothing.
- the output of `poetry config --list | grep virtualenvs` is:

```
virtualenvs.create = false
virtualenvs.in-project = null
virtualenvs.options.always-copy = false
virtualenvs.options.no-pip = false
virtualenvs.options.no-setuptools = false
virtualenvs.options.system-site-packages = false
virtualenvs.path = "{cache-dir}/virtualenvs"  # /home/jovyan/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs
virtualenvs.prefer-active-python = false
virtualenvs.prompt = "{project_name}-py{python_version}"
```

- My `pyproject.toml` is:

```ini
...

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"
ipykernel = "^6.25.1"
opencv-python = "^4.8.0.76"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

- The output of `print(sys.executable)` in notebook is `/opt/conda/bin/python`
- The output of `poetry run python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.executable)'` in IDE terminal is `/usr/local/py-utils/venvs/poetry/bin/python3`.

Comment: You're using two different Python virtual environments: the one managed by poetry, and some other one (possibly the system environment). Make sure you either a) activate the poetry environment in your current shell (`poetry shell` or `source $(poetry env info --path)/bin/activate`) or b) use `poetry run` to run a command in the virtual enviroment (e.g. `poetry run python3 -m jupyter notebook`).

Comment: See also [Basic usage - Activating the virtual environment](https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/#activating-the-virtual-environment) from the poetry docs

Comment: I use dev-container so I did not create a virtual environment for poetry. I put the `poetry.toml` file in the root of the project and added `[virtualenvs] create = false` to it. Sorry, I forgot to mention this in my question.

Comment: What do `poetry env info`, `poetry env list`, and `poetry config --list | grep virtualenvs` show?

Comment: Hmm. It looks like poetry is picking up on the system interpreter correctly, and you don't have an old venv that's getting in the way. How are you running the jupyter notebook? Does `print(sys.executable)` in the notebook match `poetry run python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.executable)'`? What interpreter is that `pip` associated with? (`pip --version`)

Comment: The output of `print(sys.executable)` in the notebook is `/opt/conda/bin/python`. But output of `poetry run python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.executable)'` is `/usr/local/py-utils/venvs/poetry/bin/python3`. These don't match.

Comment: `pip 23.2.1 from /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)` is the output of `pip --version`.

Comment: Great! So the bare `python`/`pip` commands are coming from the conda enviroment, while poetry is using the `/usr/local/py-utils/venvs/poetry` environment. Two different interpreters, hence the package mismatches. Things should work if you stick to using `poetry run` on the terminal so that you're always using poetry environment. Or might be able to convince poetry to switch to using the conda environment.

Comment: How can I convince poetry to switch to using the conda env?

Comment: I _think_ setting `virtualenvs.prefer-active-python` to `true` would do the trick

Comment: Tried, but failed. The output of `poetry run python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.executable)'` does not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the exact details, but I suspect that there is a problem with the `jupyter/datascience-notebook` image that was used to create DevContainer.

I was able to work around the problem by creating my own Docker image based on the template for poetry.

→ https://github.com/Seasawher/poetry-devcontainer